# Removing commas and unlisting a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, nlp

**Background**

I have the following sample `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Before' : [['there, are, many, different'], 
                               ['i, like, a, lot, of, sports '], 
                               ['the, middle, east, has, many']], 
                   'After' : [['in, the, bright, blue, box'], 
                               ['because, they, go, really, fast'], 
                               ['to, ride, and, have, fun'] ],

                  'P_ID': [1,2,3], 
                  'Word' : ['crayons', 'cars', 'camels'],
                  'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

                 })
```

**Output**

```
      After                          Before                       N_ID  P_ID  Word
0 [in, the, bright, blue, box]    [there, are, many, different]     A1  1   crayons
1 [because, they, go, really,fast] [i, like, a, lot, of, sports ]   A2  2   cars
2 [to, ride, and, have, fun]        [the, middle, east, has, many]  A3  3   camels
```

**Desired Output**

```
      After                          Before               N_ID  P_ID  Word
0 in the bright blue box        there are many different  A1    1   crayons
1 because they go really fast   i like a lot of sports    A2    2   cars
2 to ride and have fun         the middle east has many   A3    3   camels
```

**Question**

How do I get my desired output which is **1)** unlisted and **2)** has the commas removed?

I tried [Removing lists from each cell in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086985/removing-lists-from-each-cell-in-pandas-dataframe) to no avail

Comment: Is every cell having only a single list containing a single string with commas?

Comment: yes, that is correct. But only for the `After` and `Before` columns

Comment: In that case, it is simpler than the one you link. check my answer

Comment: The code below works great for my sample `df` shown above. But when I apply the solution below to my real dataset, my output is not quite the same. I only get one word output for the `After` and `Before` columns when it should produce an output with many words as seen below. (e.g. `in` when it should be `in the bright blue box`). Any thoughts on what could be going on?

Comment: An example from my real dataset looks like this: `[demonstrates, the, following, staining, profile, in, lesional, cells:, Positive:, CD34,, CAM5.2, Negative:, CD68,, CD45/LCA,, CD61,, CD30,, CD31,, melanoma, cocktail,, CD138,]` but after applying the code below the output looks like this: `demonstrates`

Comment: could you provide output from this command:  `df.After.head(10).values` and edit the post to add its output?

Comment: `array(['CALCIUM', 'back', 'demonstrates', 'cranial', 'back',
       'Alterations', 'showed', 'NX', 'MPV', 'MPV'], dtype=object)` . I think I see the issue. I will alter my code in a bit to reflect this difference

Comment: hah! first 10 rows of your `After` column are already single string each. There is no list at all. I can't figure out without more data correctly representing what you describe. Could you edit the post to add more sample from your real data such as the output of `df[['After', 'Before']].values`

Comment: Ok, will do. I may also post a new question to see if there is a way to convert `[demonstrates, the, following, staining, profile, in, lesional, cells:, Positive:, CD34,, CAM5.2, Negative: melanoma, cocktail,, CD138,]` into one long string `['demonstrates the following staining profile in lesional cells: Positive: CD34, CAM5.2 Negative: melanoma cocktail CD138']` to resemble my sample `df`. That way, the code you provided should work.

Comment: @AndyL. I asked a new question with an updated sample df that represents my original df. It can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918887/turn-lists-of-lists-into-strings-pandas-dataframe. Thanks for your help

Comment: I just checked. You already got a few good answers in that question. Those answers will serve you well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirmed, the solution is simple. For one column:

```
df.After.str[0].str.replace(',', '')

Out[2821]:
0         in the bright blue box
1    because they go really fast
2           to ride and have fun
Name: After, dtype: object
```

For all columns having lists, you need using `apply` and assign back as follows:

```
df.loc[:, ['After', 'Before']] = df[['After', 'Before']].apply(lambda x: x.str[0].str.replace(',', ''))


Out[2824]:
                         After                    Before N_ID  P_ID     Word
0       in the bright blue box  there are many different   A1     1  crayons
1  because they go really fast   i like a lot of sports    A2     2     cars
2         to ride and have fun  the middle east has many   A3     3   camels
```